# Apache DocumentRoot Ubuntu for Virtual Host

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, ubuntu-16.04

I'm quite puzzled by the setup of a  Virtual Host at my Apache server on Ubuntu 16.4. I did follow [this](http://wiki.processmaker.com/3.0/ProcessMaker_Ubuntu_Installation#In_Ubuntu_16.04) the instruction to install Processmaker on Ubuntu.

Everything works fine but if I access my site: http://process.koina.eu:8080 I only see the default Apache file under /var/www/html/index.html.
But my processmaker is located as in the instruction under /opt/processmaker.
In the logs everything seems running ok. The problem is that my pmos.conf is not added/recognized to the Appache configuration. Sot it makes no difference when I run "sudo a2ensite pmos.conf" or the a2dissite command and restart the server.

Comment: Does the pmos.conf file exist as /etc/apache2/sites-available/pmos.conf ?

Comment: Please post the content of your apache2 site configuration (/etc/apache2/sites-available/pmos.conf). Check the "ServerName" directive. Depending on your setup, you might want to disable the default configuration in your apache installatin.

Comment: Sorry I got distracted by to much other stuff that time. Server is not anymore in use now.

Answer (score 0):

Is there another configuration, that open port 8080 for apache? Because if pmos.conf is not recognized, you shouldn't get any answser from apache.